# Is the Facebook Client ID safe to commit to a public repository?

Tags: android, facebook, security

I'm working on an Android app and have an app_id and a client_id in a strings.xml file. It seems the app_id is safe to commit, bus is the client_id? Sorry if this is a duplicate, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe to commit to a public repository. From the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens):

> The client token is an identifier that you can embed into native mobile binaries or desktop apps to identify your app. The client token **isn't meant to be a secret identifier** because it's embedded in apps.

Emphasis mine.